# Trying to get the json variable where bootstrap tables save data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys I hope you can help me, I'm using [bootstrap table](https://examples.bootstrap-table.com/#welcomes/flat-json.html#view-source) to order the data from json query, specially this source example and I'm using chrome:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.16.0/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<table
  id="table"
  data-toggle="table"
  data-flat="true"
  data-search="true"
  data-url="http://127.0.0.0:8000/hello">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="field.name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
      <th data-field="field.count" data-sortable="true">Stargazers</th>
      <th data-field="field.count.forks" data-sortable="true">Forks</th>
      <th data-field="field.description" data-sortable="true">Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

This works fine, the problem is that If I try to re order data that previously I edit the dome with a for it shows again the data in the json object and order the row.

I think, for some reason I need to append data to the json object the server responses, the issue is that I can not see where is or which is the variable name where boostap table storage this information, I can see the json in the network option "in chrome" but I need to get the name variable to append more data.

It would help me a lot to know how to get this, any idea ?

Comment: Bootsrap table calling 'http://127.0.0.0:8000/hello' this url by ajax  and rending the table,if you want some login in your data you can do it on 'Api' or you can do which javascript or jquery.